# Is it possible to create a field on a system object?

Tags: metadata-api, custom-field, tooling-api

I need to create a field on DatedConversionRate object (advanced currency management object). The object is missing in the Object Manager, so I can not create the field via the UI.

I am not able to retrieve the object via Salesforce DX, so I created a new folder for the object manually and tried to deploy the field:

*force-app\main\default\objects\DatedConversionRate\fields\ConversionRate__c.field-meta.xml  Cannot add custom fields to entity: DatedConversionRate (165:13)*

Is there any other way how to do this, for example using Tooling or Metadata API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all standard objects support creating custom fields. `DatedConversionRate` is not *customizable* which means it *does not support* creating a custom field on it. You'll always be prevented from creating a custom field with that error message you got through your attempt

> Cannot add custom fields to entity: DatedConversionRate

[EntityDefintion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) has this field, `isCustomizable`, which lets you know when a standard object supports custom fields or not.

> If true, custom fields can be defined for the object.

You can get this info quickly through a query in the Tooling API

```
SELECT IsCustomizable,DeveloperName FROM EntityDefinition WHERE DeveloperName = 'DatedConversionRate'
```

[image]